# Drupal's Event module with View module - how to change color of past events?

Tags: events, drupal, view, module

i'm using event module, with event_views module.

is it possible to change color of past events? or events in the future?

i know that will be some extra programing, but i don't know what and where..

tnx in adv on suggestions!

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was necessary to develop a bit file `modules/views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php`